# Typescript: Change conflicting property name when extending interface

Tags: typescript, inheritance

Is there a way to do something like this with typescript, renaming the property name or something?

```
interface Person {
    name: string
    age: number
}

interface Pet {
    age: string
}

interface Zoo extends Pet, Person {}
```

Without getting this error:

> Interface 'Zoo' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Person' and 'Pet'
>   Named property 'age' of types 'Person' and 'Pet' are not identical.ts(2320)

[EDIT]

I'm looking for a way to get this result:

```
interface Zoo {
    name: string
    age: number
}
```

Comment: Can you include what you expect `Zoo` to look like structurally?  Like, if you defined it manually, what would its property keys and value types be?

Comment: By the way, you're not going to get [programmatically renamed keys](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12754), so any renaming is going to be somewhat manual (e.g., require a type like `interface RenameConflictingKeys {age: "personAge"}`).

Comment: why not just use discriminated union? age: number | string;

Comment: @jcalz just edited my question

Answer (score 5):

Ah, so you're not trying to rename properties; just remove any conflicting properties from one of the interfaces.

This is very similar to the idea of an [object spread type operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727), which TypeScript doesn't currenty have as part of the language at the type level. Currently the type system treats generic spreads as an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types), which is only correct for non-conflicting properties.)  At the value/expression level, TypeScript does properly handle spreads of concrete types, so you could get the particular `Zoo` you're looking for by convincing the type system that you have a value of type `Pet`, a value of type `Person`, and a value formed by spreading them:

```
interface Person {
  name: string
  age: number
}

interface Pet {
  age: string
  trained: boolean // I added this because otherwise Zoo=Person which is weird
}

declare const person: Person; // pretend we have a person
declare const pet: Pet; // pretend we have a pet
const zoo = { ...pet, ...person }; // spread them into a new variable
type ZooType = typeof zoo; // get the type of that variable
// type ZooType = {
//   name: string;
//   age: number;
//   trained: boolean;
// } 
interface Zoo extends ZooType { }; // make it an interface because why not
```

---

If you don't feel like mucking around with values (especially if you don't have any lying around) and you want to do this purely at the type level, you can make a spread-like type operator yourself with [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) types.  One of the language designers suggested an [implementation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316#issuecomment-359574388) of `Spread<L,R>` that works well enough with some caveats around optional/readonly/etc properties.

For your case, since you have no optional or readonly properties, here is a simpler implementation, which I'll call `Merge<L, R>`:

```
type Merge<L, R> = R & Pick<L, Exclude<keyof L, keyof R>>;
```

And you can see it behaves similarly to the above value-level spread:

```
interface Zoo extends Merge<Pet, Person> { };

declare const zoo: Zoo;
zoo.name; // string
zoo.age; // number
zoo.trained; // boolean
```

Caveats: if `age` were *optional* in `Person`, then `Merge<Pet, Person>` would make `age` optional in `Zoo`.  That *might* be what you want, but a spread wouldn't behave that way; `{...pet, ...person}` would always have an `age` since `Pet` requires one.  In a spread then, `Zoo["age"]` would be something like `string | number`, which the `Spread<L, R>` operator linked above would deal with more correctly.  Also neither `Merge<>` nor the linked `Spread<>` are guaranteed to do "the right thing" with `readonly` properties, especially since it's not clear to me what that right thing is.

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey, I got a question after I read your answer. You said " intersection is only correct for non-conflicting properties", but  I got no error  with  ```const zoo = <Person & Pet>{ ...pet, ...person }```